# Single barplot for each row of dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a csv file which looks like the following:

```
Name,Count1,Count2,Count3
application_name1,x1,x2,x3
application_name2,x4,x5,x6
```

The x variables represent numbers and the applications_name variables represent names of different applications.

Now I would like to make a barplot for each row by using ggplot2. The barplot should have the application_name as title. The x axis should show Count1, Count2, Count3 and the y axis should show the corresponding values (x1, x2, x3).

I would like to have a single barplot for each row, because I have to store the different plots in different files. So I guess I cannot use "melt".

I would like to have something like:

```
for each row in rows {
  print barplot in file
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? You definitely **can** and **should** use `melt` (with `id = "Name"`). Write a function that produces one barplot and saves it, then use `dplyr` or `plyr::ddply` to apply that function to each `Name` in your melted data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `melt` to rearrange your data and then use either `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` to get a separate plot for each application name

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# example data
mydf <- data.frame(name = paste0("name",1:4), replicate(5,rpois(4,30)))
names(mydf)[2:6] <- paste0("count",1:5)

# rearrange data
m <- melt(mydf)

# if you are wanting to export each plot separately
# I used facet_wrap as a quick way to add the application name as a plot title

for(i in levels(m$name)) {
      p <- ggplot(subset(m, name==i), aes(variable, value,  fill = variable)) + 
             facet_wrap(~ name) +
             geom_bar(stat="identity", show_guide=FALSE)

      ggsave(paste0("figure_",i,".pdf"), p)
}

# or all plots in one window
ggplot(m, aes(variable, value,  fill = variable)) + 
               facet_wrap(~ name) +
               geom_bar(stat="identity", show_guide=FALSE)
```

Comment: is it possible to make this stacked? and how so? I tried different combinations and added "position = stack" inside geom_bar() yet I could not figure it out.@user20650

Comment: @kukushkin; it depends on what you want. Using the data in this example: `ggplot(m, aes(name, value,  fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")` would be one way

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see @user20650's nice answer before preparing this. It's almost identical, except that I use `plyr::d_ply` to save things instead of a loop. I believe `dplyr::do()` is another good option (you'd `group_by(Name)` first).

```
yourData <- data.frame(Name = sample(letters, 10),
                       Count1 = rpois(10, 20),
                       Count2 = rpois(10, 10),
                       Count3 = rpois(10, 8))
library(reshape2)
yourMelt <- melt(yourData, id.vars = "Name")

library(ggplot2)
# Test a function on one piece to develope graph
ggplot(subset(yourMelt, Name == "a"), aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(title = subset(yourMelt, Name == 'a')$Name)


# Wrap it up, with saving to file
bp <- function(dat) {
    myPlot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        labs(title = dat$Name)
    ggsave(filname = paste0("path/to/save/", dat$Name, "_plot.pdf"),
           myPlot)
}

library(plyr)
d_ply(yourMelt, .variables = "Name", .fun = bp)
```