# row-wise bar plot in r

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I picked up r recently and was trying some code for data visualization. For practice, I created a small data frame to plot the data and understand the result.

First I tried plotting a simple vector, like temperature over a week, and function barplot worked like a charm.
later I moved on to plot a simple tabular data of marks of students in 2 subjects as shown below:
    stuname sub1 sub2
st1  rocket   95   70
st2     Ash   58   85

I used below to create the dataframe

```r
plotdata=data.frame("stuname"=c("rocket","Ash"),
                    "sub1"=c(95,58),
                    "sub2"=c(70,85),
                    row.names = c("st1","st2"))
```

I am using below to plot the data

```r
barplot(as.matrix(plotdata[ ,2:3]), xlab = "Stu", ylab = "marks", beside = TRUE)
```

I think the requirement is basic enough so I have not moved to ggplot yet.

This is what I'm getting:

[image: This is what I am getting]

This is what I was expecting:

[image: This is what I was expecting and want to achieve]

I mean, this is how usually we would like to plot, we can keep on adding row data and the plot can keep on increasing and I see one figure to get all the marks for a particular student.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282990/stacked-bar-plot-in-r-with-ratio-line-overplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971974/single-barplot-for-each-row-of-dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Separate just the numeric values and transpose them so that they will plot in the order you want. Note that if you transpose without separating the numeric values, they may be converted to `character`.

```
barplot(height = t(plotdata[c("sub1", "sub2")]),
        names.arg = plotdata$stuname,
        beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

I would still recommend using `ggplot` as it takes care of so many things for you

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#Convert to long format
d = melt(plotdata, id.vars = "stuname")

ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = stuname, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: so basically we transpose the data so that it becomes the column format. Do you know or can direct me to any source why such a simple implementation is missing here, i mean thats the default expectation for plotting tabular data